# Facing Nullreferenceexception while using embedded web view for MSAL authentication in iOS with .NET Maui

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, maui

facing "

```
Nullreferenceexception:object reference not set to an instance of the object"
 at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.iOS.EmbeddedWebview.EmbeddedWebUI.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Authenticate>b__0()
 at Foundation.NSObject.InvokeOnMainThread(Action acti...}
```

while performing navigation to browser. The same code worked for me before in Xamarin Forms but failing .NET Maui targeting .NET 8 with iOS platform. Microsoft.Identity.Client version 4.58.0 used.

```
    PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scope)
                    .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(null)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
```

please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Anyone to help?